# C++ Timer for my C++ Game

Tags: c++

I've encountered a huge problem! I'm making a C++ Zombie game and it works perfectly besides the barrier part. I want the zombies to come to the barrier, then have them wait around 5 seconds, and then break through the barrier. Now I don't think you need my whole code for this since it's just a timer, but if you do let me know! Basically, I tried many timers AND the Sleep command, but when I use them it makes the zombies stay at the barrier, but then everything else freezes until the timers. For exmaple if the zombies at the barrier and I use a timer for 5 seconds, the zombie stays at the barrier for 5 seconds! but so does everything else, nothing else can move for 5 seconds! Is their any way I could use a sleep command only for a CERTAIN part of my code? Here is one of the few timers I used.

```
int Timer()
{
int s = 0;
int m = 0;
int h = 0;
while (true)
{
    CPos(12,58);
    cout << "Timer: ";
    cout << h/3600 << ":" << m/60 << ":" << s;

    if (s == 59) s = -1;
    if (m == 3599) m = -1;      //3599 = 60*60 -1
    s++;
    m++;
    h++;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout<<"\b\b\b";
}
}
```

This one involves a sleep command, I also used a timer where while(number > 0) --number, but it works! but it still freezes everything else in my program!

If you need anything, Let me know!

Comment: One way you could handle this is to add a status flag and a counter to the zombies and when they hit the wall you set the flag, and while the flag is set you decrease the counter in every update until it reaches zero and then you let them pass the wall. It's a poor mans state handler.

Comment: "Works perfectly" in a Stack Overflow question is the most reliable symptom yet that the poster is deeply confused about the subject matter in question. One might say that the implication works perfectly.

Comment: What is the rest of your program going to do while waiting for the timer?  Whatever it is, do *that* while checking for the desired time to have elapsed.

Comment: @jpw How would I add a flag?

Comment: @indiv Bascially the zombies just keep on doing everything their suppose to do! nothing should change, even if the zombie is at the barrier other zombies should try to keep getting to it.

Comment: @SirRyan98 Without knowing anything about what your code looks like, how you handle states/events etc I really can't say. This question seem very broad and there's many different ways of accomplishing what you want, but until you narrow the question a bit I don't think SO is a good fit for the question.

Comment: @jpw Is their anyway I can send you my code personally? Because I have been working very hard on it.

Comment: @SirRyan98 I'm afraid not, I don't do personal support.

Comment: @SirRyan98:  How often do your other zombies think or move?  Once per millisecond?  Once per second?

Comment: @jpw  Here is part of my code! Don't worry what goes above it because it's long! and Map generally means my char map[][] the zombies move if theirs is a space they keep moving along the x axis, and I also put in the timer function where it needs to go but don't know how to imply a timer that doesn't freeze everything! I hope this narrows it done. The code is in the comment below!

Comment: case 'z':
     repeat:
     CPos(y,x);
     SetColor(10);
     if((Map[y][x+1] == ' ')||Map[y][x+1] == '*') { Map[y][x] = ' '; CPos(y,x); cout << ' '; x++; Map[y][x] = 'z'; CPos(y,x); SetColor(10); cout << (char)2; 
     }
     if(Map[y][x+1] == 'B') { 
      int number = 0;
      while(number != 5) {
       Sleep(100);
       number ++;
      }
      if(Map[y][x+1] == 'B' && number == 5) { Map[y][x+1] = 'D';
      }
     }
     break;
    case 'D':
     CPos(y,x);
     SetColor(7);
     cout << (char)177;
     break;
    } // end switch

Comment: also here is the code for B if you need it!     case 'B':
     CPos(y,x);
     SetColor(7);
     cout << (char)178;
     break;

Comment: @indiv I coudln't tag you both at once! But the code is above!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have EACH zombie and everything else running on different threads, calling Sleep will pause the entire application for x milliseconds... You need to stop the zombie a different way, namely by just not moving him until the time has passed, while still updating the other entities as normal (don't use sleep).

EDIT:

You can't just create a timer and then wait until that timer is done.  At the time when the zombie needs to stop moving, you have to 'remember' the current time, but continue on.  Then each time you get back to that zombie again to update its position, you check to see if he has a pause timer.  If he does, then you have to compare the elapsed time between what you 'remembered' against the current time and check whether he has paused long enough...  here is some psuedo code:

```
#include <time>

class Zombie {
private:
  int m_xPos;
  time_t m_rememberedTime;

public:
  Zombie() {
    this->m_xPos = 0;
    this->m_rememberedTime = 0;
  }

  void Update() {
    if (CheckPaused()) {
      // bail out before we move this zombie if he is paused at a barrier.
      return;
    }

    // If it's not paused, then move him as normal.
    this->m_xPos += 1;  // or whatever.

    if (ZombieHitBarrier()) {
      PauseZombieAtBarrier();
    }
  }

  bool CheckPaused() {
    if (this.m_rememberedTime > 0) {
      // If we have a remembered time, calculate the elapsed time.
      time_t currentTime;
      time(&currentTime);
      time_t elapsed = currentTime - this.m_rememberedTime;
      if (elapsed > 5.0f) {
        // 5 seconds has gone by, so clear the remembered time and continue on to return false.
        this.m_rememberedTime = 0;
      } else {
        // 5 seconds has not gone by yet, so return true that we are still paused.
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Either no timer exists, or the timer has just finished, return false that we are not paused.
    return false;
  }

  // Call this when the zombie hits a wall.
  void PauseZombieAtBarrier() {
    // Store the current time in a variable for later use.
    time(&this->m_rememberedTime);
  }
};
```

Comment: How would you suppose I do something like that?

Comment: During the update loop for each individual zombie, you check if that zombie has a timer on them, if they do and the timer is not finished yet, do not move the zombie.  Whatever you do, do not do any kind of `while(true)` type thing that will block other code from executing while the wait happens.

Comment: In the comment above, i posted some more code, if you can could you like at how I set it up and maybe imply that into the code! I'm still confused

Comment: Wait.. Is that C++ code? or C# Because I need C++! :)

Comment: It's just an example, but it should be C++.